# Generalization of Bessel function integral

Tags: calculus, bessel-functions, integration

An integral involving Bessel functions and exponentials is given in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, Equation 6.653 2.) :

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} x -\frac{1}{2x}(z^2+w^2)\right] K_{\nu}\left(\frac{zw}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x} = 2K_{\nu}(z) 2K_{\nu}(w) \\ 
|\text{arg}z|,|\text{arg}w|<\pi, \text{arg}(z+w)<\frac{1}{4}\pi
$$

I am interested in how one might obtain this formula, and whether it could be generalized for arbitrary positive or negative integer powers of $x$ beyond $x^{-1}$.

Comment: The technique is explained here https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43491/7/Volume%202.pdf